# How to manipulate URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to manipulate URL, the URL like this

```
http://localhost/project/1/my-stuff
```

where `1` is id and `my-stuff` is a slug, I want to change become

```
http://localhost/project/my-stuff
```

I try to change the route like this

```
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/$1/$2';
```

but it doesn't work, the id is very important I cannot delete it, but how to hide id in url, sorry for my english bad.

Comment: One way would be redirecting in controller on every successfull request. Another way would be making DB query to work with columns of ('my-stuff') instead of id. Second one is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't get it, can you give me an example?

Comment: You are queryng DB by id and set layout and so on. You can change your code to query db by slug.

Comment: I need id too,
`function index($id, $slug) {
$data['item'] = $this->db->get_where('tb_stuff', array('id' => $id)->result();
$data['pic'] = $this->db->get_where('tb_pic', array('slug' => $slug)->result();
}`
more or less like this, I cannot left the id

Comment: If `id` and `slug` don't belong to same row of the same table, I don't think it is possible to avoid `id` in URL.

Comment: Make your `slug` unique per row and use it to query the table. In the result row, you can access the `id` if needed.

Comment: Hi @Yulianto, Just  use $route['project/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'project/$1/$2';

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove the id from the url if you need it.
you can either use POST variable or store in the `$this->session` object and use it in your controller to get the needed ID.

[Here take a look on how to use the session library in CI](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)